# CSS & Javascript issues with a hamburger menu and an image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I was following 2 youtube tutorials while working on a website. One tutorial was on building a complete website that's responsive and the second was on creating an image gallery with a grid layout. The end result that I had when I finished working on my website looked good but I noticed two problems.

When you decrease the size of the website so that it takes up half of your screen, the navbar shrinks down and you get a hamburger menu. But clicking on the hamburger isn't opening it up like it should. There's an eventListener that should be adding and removing a class called active but nothing is happening.

This is the html code that contains the navbar and hamburger icon

```
<header>
    <a href="#" class="logo">Glitta Art Studio</a>
    <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>

    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

This is the CSS for the media query

```
@media(max-width: 1140px) {
    section {
        padding: 50px 8%;
    }
    #menu-icon {
        display: initial;
        color: var(--text-color);
    }
    header .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: -400px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        background: #2b2640;
        transition: .3s;
    }
        header .navbar .active {
            top: 70px;
        }
        .navbar a {
            padding: 1.5rem;
            display: block;
        }
        .col {
            width: 50%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
}
```

And here's the JavaScript

```
let menu = document.querySelector("#menu-icon");
let navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    navbar.classList.toggle("active")
});

window.onscroll = () => {
    navbar.classList.remove("active");
};
```

The second problem is technically not as big of a deal as the nav, but it's been more annoying for me to deal with so far. When you move your mouse over one of the images in the gallery section, a white box appears over the image with a title of the image and some information about it. But for some reason, the person in the tutorial added an a tag to the text in these boxes and I blindly added that to my project without thinking. Clicking on the box brings you back up to the homepage so I want to get rid of that completely and not have it link to anything. I'm not sure what the issue is with the CSS, but if you try to remove the a tags in the html and replace them with a regular p tag then it completely ruins the the grid of images and they all get stuck on one side of the screen.

Here's the HTML code of the gallery (There's 10 divs exactly like this with the same filler text and temporary image)

```
<div class="image-gallery">
            <div class="image-box">
                <img src="img/paintbrush.jpeg" alt="paintbrush">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h3 class="title">
                            <a href="">Painting Title</a>
                        </h3>
                        <span class="category">
                            <a href="">text about piece here</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-box">
                <img src="img/paintbrush.jpeg" alt="paintbrush">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h3 class="title">
                            <a href="#">Painting Title</a>
                        </h3>
                        <span class="category">
                            <a href="#">text about piece here</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
.gallery {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.image-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px,1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 250px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.image-gallery .image-box {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d7d7d8;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:nth-child(7n + 1){
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
}

.image-gallery .image-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.image-gallery .image-box .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fafaf2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover .overlay {
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details {
    text-align: center;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details .title {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details .category {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -5px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover .details .title {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 0.3s 0.2s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover .details .category {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 0.3s 0.2s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details .title a,
.image-gallery .image-box .details .category a {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Sorry for asking these basic questions. I haven't practiced coding anything in a long while so I've forgotten a lot of things.

Edit: I was able to fix the gallery issue. Now its just the hamburger issue that I have to deal with

Comment: Clicking on a functionless  button/tag will reload the page so you need to get rid of that tags

Comment: @BahramGozalov I tried to get rid of the a tags, but for some reason that completely messes up the CSS of the grid of images

Comment: Could you provide the css of the div with the id of "menu-icon" in the comments please?

Comment: @BahramGozalov #menu-icon {
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 1140px) {
 
    #menu-icon {
        display: initial;
        color: var(--text-color);
    }
 }

Comment: Is the width of your screen always lower than 1140 px as otherwise the display of the div is none

Comment: And you can try implying the onclick in the element itself(HTML):

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try implying the function in the HTML element itself like this:

`<div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon" onclick="ToggleClassActive()"></div>`

and you need to delete the eventlistener function and use this instead

```
    function ToggleClassActive(){
        let menu = document.querySelector("#menu-icon");
        let navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
        navbar.classList.toggle("active");
    }
```

You also need to ensure that the script is after the elements(The best place to place your script is right before the

And could you please show the error which occurs in the console

Comment: I tried using this code but the menu still isn't opening up and the only messages in the console are: 

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mihdfbecejheednfigjpdacgeilhlmnf/react-draggable.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fgmojdlldojifnjgpnhmfdchbiapfjhb/css/content.css.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @NotBrandX did you try disabling your adblock or any other extension?